# if parent has child class then hide mother div secondchild class with CSS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Will you please tell me that how i hide mother `.secondchild` if parent has child class.

Here is the code

HTML code

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        children
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mother">
    <div class="secondchild">
        second-child
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script but not working

```
if ($(".parent").hasClass("child")) {    
    $('.mother .secondchild').hide()
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: it's already format @EugeneMihaylin

Comment: @EugeneMihaylin please check and tell me how to do this

Comment: @bemo check answer.

Comment: You can't do this using CSS

Comment: Please read more about jQuery methods. I see that you are confused about `hasClass` and about `click` ( i saw in the comments you want to remove someting when user clicks on a button ) . There are a bunch of docs and tutorials for this basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your parent div has no class called child, your script won't give the desired output.
try this

```
if($('.parent').children().hasClass('child')){
    $('.mother .secondchild').hide();
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bfwxqaLg/)

**EDIT**

Based on OP's Comment hidden the div in the button click.

Html

```
<button id="btnClick">
Click Me
</button>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click','#btnClick','',function(){
   if($('.parent').children().hasClass('child')){
      $('.mother .secondchild').hide();
   }
});
```

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bfwxqaLg/1/)

Comment: thanks for your great answer but my div child class enter when click on button but when i click on that button then this script not working :( please tell me how to do that

Comment: @bemo do you want to hide the div on button click?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function(){
        $("body").on("click",".click",function(){
            if ($(".parent ").children("div.child")) {
                $('.mother .secondchild').hide()
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            children
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="secondchild">
            second-child
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="click">
        button
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer but my div child class enter when click on button but when i click on that button then this script not working :( please tell me how to do that

Comment: Now please check i have added a button as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Do this work without any `if` condition

```js
$(".parent:has(.child)").next().find(".secondchild").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    children
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mother">
  <div class="secondchild">
    second-child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer but my div child class enter when click on button but when i click on that button then this script not working :( please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You just change "hasclass" to "has", then it works.

```
if($('.parent').has('.child')){
   $('.mother .secondchild').hide();
}
```